# SQL- Getting maximum value along with all other columns?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table, which can be seen as a evaluation of two courses in several classroom tests, like this:

```
student_ID     Evaluation           Course1   Course2
------------------------------------------------------
1                   5                 88         93
2                   4                 70         87
1                   5                 93         90
2                   5                 99         91
3                   3                 65         60
3                   4                 88         70
```

I need to get the result of the Evaluation=5 for each student, if any.  If that student has more than one Evaluation=5, the query only show any one of them.  So for the above example table, the query result will be

```
student_ID     Evaluation           Course1   Course2
------------------------------------------------------
1                   5                 88         93
2                   5                 99         91
```

Of course in my real table, the "Courses" number is more than 2.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Since you only want to get only one record for every `student_id`, you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` which generates sequential number. The number generated will always starts with `1` which you can use to filter out row for every partition, in this case `Student_ID`.

```
SELECT  Student_ID, Evaluation, Course1, Course2
FROM    
        (
            SELECT  Student_ID, Evaluation, Course1, Course2,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Student_ID 
                    ORDER BY Student_ID) rn
            FROM    TableName
            WHERE   Evaluation = 5
        ) a
WHERE   a.rn = 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/09d85/1)

Comment: Oh my god!  You are so quick.  Thanks a lot.